# How to get a Calendar prompt and insert date

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm writing a function that takes two dates as arguments. (something like 2016-8-1)

I would like to get the dates from the beautiful emacs calendar view.

```
(defun my-fun (date1 date2)
   (setq date1 (get-date-from-calendar))
)
```

I know in Org mode there is

```
C-c .     (org-time-stamp)
```

But when used in elisp code, this function expect arguments.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you want a pretty 3-month calendar that temporily pops-open and then closes again, consider using `org-read-date` in conjunction with a custom function of your choosing.

Answer (score 1):

The argument is used to pass a prefix option if you want to avoid prompting the user. You can just pass nil and it should work `(org-time-stamp nil)`

Answer (score 1):

```lisp
(defun org-read-date-example ()
  "Doc-string."
  (require 'org)
  (let ((date-in-string-format (org-read-date nil nil nil "Date #1:  "))
        (date-in-time-format (org-read-date nil 'to-time nil "Date #2:  ")))
    (message "Date #1: %s | Date #2: %s" date-in-string-format date-in-time-format)))
```